# Adding html to helper_methods to custom flash messages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am using rails 6 with TailwindCss 1.0+ and I am currently trying to build out a custom flash message box.

I have a helper module with 3 case statements in it.

**Statement # 1 the flash class**

```
  def flash_class(level)
    case level
      when :notice then 'alert-info'
      when :success then 'alert-success'
      when :error then 'alert-error'
      when :alert then 'alert-error'
    end
  end
```

**Statement # 2 the flash_icon** (I want to add an `.svg` icon to the flash box based on the flash) class

```
  def flash_icon(img)
    case img
      when :notice then content_tag :div class: "py-1" end  :svg class: "fill-current h-6 w-6 text-white mr-2"  xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox: "0 0 20 20" end :path d: "M2.93 17.07A10 10 0 1 1 17.07 2.93 10 10 0 0 1 2.93 17.07zm12.73-1.41A8 8 0 1 0 4.34 4.34a8 8 0 0 0 11.32 11.32zM9 11V9h2v6H9v-4zm0-6h2v2H9V5z" end
    end
  end
```

This is where I believe the majority of my issues are coming from. there are a few different tag types here like `div`, `svg`, `d`, and i really am not too sure how to handle those in the helper method.

**Statement # 3 Alert Title Text** (this one I can figure out once I figure out how to handle content tags in helper methods)[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
  def flash_status_text(status)
    case status
      when :notice then content_tag :p class: "text-sm" Some Status Here end
    end
  end
end
```

**These are the errors I'm getting when trying to navgate to my site:**

```
/Users/shawnwilson/Desktop/Development/Fuze Group/LoadzeWeb/app/helpers/flash_helper.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected class, expecting end ...ice then content_tag :div class: "py-1" end :svg class: "fi... ... ^~~~~ /Users/shawnwilson/Desktop/Development/Fuze Group/LoadzeWeb/app/helpers/flash_helper.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end ...t_tag :div class: "py-1" end :svg class: "fill-current h-6 ... ... ^ /Users/shawnwilson/Desktop/Development/Fuze Group/LoadzeWeb/app/helpers/flash_helper.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end ...h-6 w-6 text-white mr-2" xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg... ... ^~~~~ /Users/shawnwilson/Desktop/Development/Fuze Group/LoadzeWeb/app/helpers/flash_helper.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end ...://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox: "0 0 20 20" end :path d: "M... ... ^~~~~~~ /Users/shawnwilson/Desktop/Development/Fuze Group/LoadzeWeb/app/helpers/flash_helper.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input ...svg" viewBox: "0 0 20 20" end :path d: "M2.93 17.07A10 10 0 ... ... ^
```

**EDIT: ADDS ORIGINAL TailwindCSS alert box html & what i'm trying to achieve**

**Original:**

```
<div class="bg-teal-100 border-t-4 border-teal-500 rounded-b text-teal-900 px-4 py-3 shadow-md" role="alert">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="py-1"><svg class="fill-current h-6 w-6 text-teal-500 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M2.93 17.07A10 10 0 1 1 17.07 2.93 10 10 0 0 1 2.93 17.07zm12.73-1.41A8 8 0 1 0 4.34 4.34a8 8 0 0 0 11.32 11.32zM9 11V9h2v6H9v-4zm0-6h2v2H9V5z"/></svg></div>
    <div>
      <p class="font-bold">Our privacy policy has changed</p>
      <p class="text-sm">Make sure you know how these changes affect you.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I want:**

```
<div class="<%= flash_class(level) %> border-t-4 border-teal-500 rounded-b text-teal-900 px-4 py-3 shadow-md" role="alert">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="py-1"><%= flash_icon(img) %></div>
    <div>
      <%= flash_status_text(status) %>
      <p class="text-sm"><%= message %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the html you're expecting to create?

Comment: @SebastianPalma see edit above - ill add where i want to put the various case keys in the html

Comment: @SebastianPalma Updated Top is tailwind message box bottom is what im trying to acheive

Comment: Do you want to put the whole `svg` and children into the `class` selector of the first div? Would that work somehow?

Comment: @SebastianPalma if i could do something like a case statement that handles the entire div from levle to status i'm ok with that. i thought it may have been less hassle to do a case statement for each area i wanted to modify based on flash type

Comment: @SebastianPalma like i said im really new to the helper methods so im ok to pursure the best way that makes the most sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible and shouldn't be so difficult.

I'd like to take a more OOP approach than using `case` statements:

```
# helpers/<model_name>/flash/flash.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Users
  module Flash
    class Flash
      ALERT_PREFIX = 'alert-'
      XMLNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'

      include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
      include ActionView::Context

      def class_attr; end

      def status_text; end

      def icon; end
    end
  end
end
```

This class defines the common method for each inherited object (success, info, error, alert), constants and external modules to include.

```
# helpers/<model_name>/flash/notice.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Users
  module Flash
    class Notice < Flash
      def class_attr
        "#{ALERT_PREFIX}info"
      end

      def status_text
        content_tag(:p, 'Some Status', class: 'text-sm')
      end

      def icon
        content_tag(
          :svg,
          class: 'fill-current h-6 w-6 text-teal-500 mr-4',
          xmlns: XMLNS,
          viewBox: '0 0 20 20') do
            content_tag(
              :path,
              nil,
              d: 'M2.93 17.07A10 10 0 1 1 17.07 2.93 10 10 0 0 1 2.93 17.07zm12.73-1.41A8 8 0 1 0 4.34 4.34a8 8 0 0 0 11.32 11.32zM9 11V9h2v6H9v-4zm0-6h2v2H9V5z'
            )
          end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The files inheriting from `Flash` redefine the methods by their own logic. This time without conditions.

When a method isn't defined in the `Flash` child class, then it returns nil, as it invokes the method in its parent class, which doesn't have a body, so returns just `nil`.

```
# helpers/<model_name>/flash/error.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Users
  module Flash
    class Error < Flash
      def class_attr
        "#{ALERT_PREFIX}error"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can just instantiate the class and invoke the method needed:

```
<%= <model_name>::Flash::Notice.new.class_attr %>
<%= <model_name>::Flash::Notice.new.status_text %>
<%= <model_name>::Flash::Notice.new.icon %>
```

---

Notice to create the `svg` and `path` HTML elements, I've used nested `content_tag`s. `svg` has its class defined, plus the needed options (`xmlns`, `viewbox`), which allows you to open a block and to put `path` inside, which has a `nil` argument, as it renders no more content than the tag itself.

`d` is just added in `path` taking advantage of the options argument the `content_tag` method accepts.

```
def icon
  content_tag(
    :svg,
    class: 'fill-current h-6 w-6 text-teal-500 mr-4',
    xmlns: XMLNS,
    viewBox: '0 0 20 20') do
      content_tag(
        :path,
        nil,
        d: 'M2.93 17.07A10 10 0 1 1 17.07 2.93 10 10 0 0 1 2.93 17.07zm12.73-1.41A8 8 0 1 0 4.34 4.34a8 8 0 0 0 11.32 11.32zM9 11V9h2v6H9v-4zm0-6h2v2H9V5z'
      )
    end
end
```

Comment: THANK YOU for such a detailed explination and taking a different approach to this problem! i did get it going (I made a gist about it) https://gist.github.com/apocolyptic/1f23bd5e8bf385320b6c4903f75c08c7 please let me know what you think of this approach as well! i am going to try your way above here today aswell!